# How to style an a element that redirects to react component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js:

```js
import './App.css';
import logo from './images/logo.png';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Calculators from './components/Calculators';
import Classes from './components/Classes';
import Riddles from './components/Riddles';
import { useRoutes, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const MenuBar = () => {
  return (
    <header className='App-header'>
    <div className="container">
      <a id="home" className="content-tab" href="/"> Home</a>
      <a id="about" className="content-tab" href="/about"> About</a>
      <a id="calcs" className="content-tab" href="/calculators">  Calculators</a>
      <a id="riddles" className="content-tab" href="/riddles">Riddles</a>
      <a id="classes" className="content-tab" href="/classes">Classes</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  let routes = useRoutes([
    { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
    { path: "about", element: <About /> },
    { path: "classes", element: <Classes />},
    { path: "calculators", element: <Calculators />},
    { path: "riddles", element: <Riddles /> },
    // ...
  ]);
  return routes;
};

function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MenuBar />
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppWrapper;
```

Now, I want to make that whenever you select a page, like home, about, calculators, etc; it marks the link using `border-bottom: 1px solid white;`, but when using

```css
.container a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

It just doesn't work.
Any ideas why?
Can it be because it's redirecting to a different url?
If so, then should I also import app.css into my Home, About, etc components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Link`, or `NavLink` if you want to apply active styling, instead of the raw anchor `<a />` tag. Use the `function` callback for the `className` prop which is passed an `isActive` prop.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const MenuBar = () => {
  const getLinkClassNames = ({ isActive }) => [
    "content-tab",
    isActive ? "active-tab" : null,
  ]
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join(" ");

  return (
    <header className='App-header'>
      <div className="container">
        <NavLink
          id="home"
          className={getLinkClassNames}
          to="/"
        >
          Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          id="about"
          className={getLinkClassNames}
          to="/about"
        >
          About
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          id="calcs"
          className={getLinkClassNames}
          to="/calculators"
        >
          Calculators
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          id="riddles"
          className={getLinkClassNames}
          to="/riddles"
        >
          Riddles
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          id="classes"
          className={getLinkClassNames}
          to="/classes"
        >
          Classes
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.active-tab {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

If you prefer the v5 syntax then create a custom `NavLink` component.

```
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavLink = React.forwardRef(
  ({ activeClassName, activeStyle, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <BaseNavLink
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
        className={({ isActive }) =>
          [
            props.className,
            isActive ? activeClassName : null
          ]
            .filter(Boolean)
            .join(" ")
        }
        style={({ isActive }) => ({
          ...props.style,
          ...(isActive ? activeStyle : null)
        })}
      />
    );
  }
);
```

Usage:

```
<NavLink
  id="home"
  className="content-tab"
  activeClassName="active-tab"
  to="/"
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```